# Containers can't resolve service IPs with Consul DNS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns, consul

I'm setting up a Consul + Registrar + HaProxy + Docker project but have some trouble to get the service discovery working over DNS.

The Consul setup works perfect, the services get correctly registered/deregistered when containers are started or stopped. The HaProxy works perfect and redirects the traffic to the correct backend servers.

The only thing I can't get to work is the DNS resolvement of services within containers.

**What does work:**

- pinging the other containers on IP.
- using `dig` with the DNS server IP to get services IP addresses (`dig @consul_server servicex.service.consul`).

**What doesn't work:**

- using `dig` without the DNS server IP (`dig servicex.service.consul`).
- using `dig` with DNS server IP but without domain specification (`dig @consul_server servicex`).
- ping on service name results in error `ping: bad address 'servicex'` or `ping: bad address 'servicex.service.consul'`.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  consul_server:
    image: consul:1.14.5
    container_name: consul_server
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=ConsulServer
    networks:
      - consul
    ports:
      - 8400:8400 # requests from CLI
      - 8500:8500 # HTTP API requests
      - 53:53/udp # DNS
    command: "agent -server -ui -node=server-1 -bootstrap -dns-port=53 -client=0.0.0.0"

  registrator:
    image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
    container_name: registrator
    networks:
      - consul
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=Registrator
    command: "-internal=true -cleanup=true consul://consul_server:8500"
    depends_on:
      - consul_server
  
  haProxy:
    image: haproxy:2.4
    container_name: haProxy
    sysctls: 
      - net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=0
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=HaProxy
    volumes:
      - ./haProxy/config/:/usr/local/etc/haproxy:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 1936:1936
    networks:
      - consul
    depends_on:
      - consul_server

  containerA:
    image: hashicorp/counting-service:0.0.2
    container_name: containerA
    expose: 
      - 9001
    dns:
      - consul_server
      - 8.8.8.8
    dns_search: service.consul
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=servicex
      - SERVICE_TAGS=containerA
    networks:
      - consul
    depends_on:
      - registrator

  containerB:
    image: hashicorp/counting-service:0.0.2
    container_name: containerB
    ports: 
      - 9001
    dns:
      - consul_server
      - 8.8.8.8
    dns_search: service.consul
    environment:
      - SERVICE_NAME=servicex
      - SERVICE_TAGS=containerB
    networks:
      - consul
    depends_on:
      - registrator

networks:
  consul:
    driver: bridge
```